# Why is text inside <head> tag rendered?

Tags: html

If I put some text inside `<head>` tag of an HTML page, this text is rendered by popular browsers like Chrome or Firefox (see the MWE below). Is it an expected behavior?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head> Foo Bar </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text nodes are not allowed inside the head element, but the end tag for it is optional, so the text node implicitly ends the head element and starts the body.

The end tag for the head element has no matching start tag so is discarded as an error.

This is expected error recovery behaviour.

Use a markup validator.

Comment: This becomes clear. But if I add a ```<title>``` tag after the text node, this title is well displayed in my tab. Does this mean that: 1. the text node first implicitly closes the ```<head>``` tag, but 2. that the browser creates a new ```<head>``` tag as soon as it sees the ```<title>``` tag?

Comment: It moves the title element inside the existing head. Read the parsing rules in the HTML 5 spec.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to quentin's answer - it is good to realise that browsers handle html errors loosley. They try to 'render as much as they can. This is in one way to aid developers and in an other way better for user experience. This makes it so a single error somewhere does not stop the whole document from rendering (or showing a fat warning) - which is generally more appreciated by the end-user.

Interesting (background) info:

[Tag soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup)

[Error tolerance in browsers](https://codeburst.io/how-browsers-work-6350a4234634)